# Storing an array with repeating elements

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm working on a project where each user has an inventory, which is really just an array of IDs that correspond to actual things in the project.

To store the inventory, I want to use Postgres and just serialize/deserialize data into a string format. However, in this array it is likely that they will have many of a single ID. The IDs are all integers so I'm planning on just joining them with a comma and separating them out during retrieval.

For example, the inventory might be `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]`, but it would be best not to store it like `1,2,3,3,3,4` with a long repeating list.

Is there an efficient way to store duplicate items?

Comment: If you are storing the data is String format why not convert it to JSON which is supported by the latest Postgres DB?

Comment: Oh, didn't know that existed. Well, even if I'm storing it as a JSON array, I'd still like a way to compress it. I think I've got a solution, will post it as answer.

Comment: PostgreSQL also supports array columns so you could use an `int[]` column. Or just use a separate table so that you can have proper referential integrity in your database. Also, how huge are these arrays and how many duplicates do they have that you think this sort of optimization is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

"Actual things in the project" should be another table in the database.  The correct *relational* approach is to have a junction table:

```
create table userItems as (
    userItemId serial primary key,
    userId int references users(userId),
    itemId int references items(itemId)
);
```

You can then add additional information -- such as quantity, price, date when added, and so on.

There are some circumstances where an array would be more appropriate.  However, for run-of-the-mill situations where you have users and items, a junction table would be the first approach and most likely to solve your problem.

Comment: The problem with this is that the "Actual things in the project" aren't in the database. I have some functions that convert the IDs into meaningful data for the application, so storing the items on the database wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nishant I realized I can store the array in the JSON format instead. With this I can do the compression like this (using the original input):

```
{
    "1": 1,
    "2": 1,
    "3": 3,
    "4": 1
}
```

Which will allow me to just store a count of each element in the JSON.

EDIT: Here's the code.

```
function(array) {
    output = {};
    array.forEach((x) => {
        output[x] = (output[x] || 0) + 1
    });
    return output;
}
```